# PyDev unresolved import with sklearn

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, pydev, scikit-learn

I'm running PyDev in Eclipse 4.2 on Mountain Lion. I installed the [SciPy Superpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/), and can use all the packages -- including Scikit-learn and MatPlotLib -- in the Python interpreter and through IPython. However, when I try to import them in PyDev I get an 'Unresolved import' error.

I installed Python 2.7.3 from Python.org, and verified that PyDev is pointing to the correct interpreter. I also attempted to add the sklearn and matplotlib directories (verified via the path from `sklearn.__file__`) to the System PYTHONPATH in the PyDev settings. This didn't resolve the issue.

Any idea what else I should try?

Comment: Did you add them to the forced builtins, in that same preference location? Also, can you post an example of the paths you added to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. It eliminates the initial unresolved import error, but throws it again as soon as I try to use anything the modules actually contain. 'from sklearn import datasets' is still unresolved, for example.

Comment: Example of path added to PYTHONPATH: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.12_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/sklearn/'

Comment: Ya that path would be incorrect. You only need the site-packages level, and the egg level. Not inside. The way you have it now would allow:  import datasets

Comment: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/' is also in the PYTHONPATH. It still didn't work, even with the packages added to Forced Builtins and only the site-packages level in the PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment examples, seems the path you are using is at the wrong depth.

Change from:
`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.12_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel‌​.egg/sklearn`

To:
`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.12_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel‌​.egg`

It wasn't able to find the package level name because you were specifying beneath it. Normally a python interpreter will resolve all the eggs by simply existing insite the site-packages, from the `.pth' file references that get placed there. But I think pyDev will need explicit adding of those eggs to the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, and it now doesn't generate an error at the import line, but still doesn't let me use any of the actual members. So "from sklearn import datasets", or "from matplotlib import pyplot" work, but then "iris = datasets.load_iris()" or "pyplot.plot([1,2,3])"  result in "Unidentified variable from import" errors.

Comment: ACTUALLY: Turns out it works when I run it; however, the error is still there.

Comment: It would still work when you ran it no matter what, because the interpreter would find it. The problem was having pyDev resolve it in the IDLE